Drop down menu that updates block content
I want to have a drop down menu/list as part of the content of a specific page where you select a country and the content of that section of the page updates with country specific content. So when you select "French" in the drop down list, you'll see a link to download a pdf in French, if you select "English" in the drop down list, you'll see a link to download a pdf in English, etc. There'll be a bit more than just a link to a pdf but that is the gist of it.
How do I go about doing that? Can it be achieved easily with custom code somehow?
Thanks!

I removed the part about asking if there's a plugin, recommendations are off-topic here

Everything can be achieved but it's tough to answer your question without seeing what you're building and having some code to review and work with.  I would simply load all of the different language content onto the page and then hide it.  But then use the filter to determine which content to show.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@TonyDjukic Unfortunately I can't share a site because the content is confidential but you're describing exactly what I want: Loading all the different language content onto the page, hiding it and then using a filter (via a drop down) to show the correct content. How would I do that?

You don't need to share the link and we don't need to see the actual confidential content.  What I mean is we don't know what its being built with? We don't know what sort of access you have or what capabilities you're working with. Is it a custom theme, a child theme, are you using a page builder, is the content being placed on the page with the Block Editor, Classic Editor, Beaver Builder, DIVI, Elementor... ...depending on all these details, the capabilities of what can be done and the best way to do something like this drastically changes.

I would hide them all by default except for the most common language.  Then I would use jQuery and on the <select> element (dropdown) I would use .on( 'change' ) to check which language had been selected and then hide every language EXCEPT for that one and display every document link for that language.  For this to work I have to be able add a data-lang="" attribute to each of the document links, so that I can target them based on what the dropdown is changed to.
Now even with what I wrote above, HOW to do it changes based on what you're working with.

@TonyDjukic Sorry, that makes sense. I am using the Twenty Twenty Four theme and have admin access. I haven't created it as a child theme but I'm wondering if maybe I should do that first. Also, what you described in the comment is a little above my head. I only have limited knowledge of coding but I appreciate all the help you can give me. :)

If you don't set up a child theme, then you'll need to build a plugin, which is a bit more work than just adding code to a child theme.  I'd start here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#how-to-create-a-child-theme

I have just set up a child theme of Twenty Twenty Four. So how would I go about creating the filter/drop down now? :)
